# HDBSCAN Cluster choice

Tags: scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, unsupervised-learning, hdbscan

I have been working with `HDBSCAN` and have a few hundreds of clusters based on my data. I am trying to select some cluster groups for further analysis. Looking for the clusters which have high inter-cluster-distance, as in more spread out and behave bit outlier-ish than the rest of the cluster. As of now, I was working with the (`-1`)clusters category but realized that `cluster.probabilities_` of these clusters are `0`. I need this value for further analysis.

**My question is**:

1. What does `cluster.probabilities_` score say about a cluster?
2. And is there any way (other than just choosing the `-1` cluster category) I can select some other clusters where there might be possibilities of outliers as well? As in calculating inter-cluster-distance or maybe some other way?

Answer (score 0):

1. `cluster.probabilities_` means the probability that given data point belongs to that cluster
2. -1 means that this data point has been labeled as noise. If you want them to be allocated [Soft Clustering](https://hdbscan.readthedocs.io/en/latest/soft_clustering.html) might be a solution